# Checking NSUserDefaults before view is shown

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, viewdidload

Currently, I have 2 UIViews - Login View and User Profile View.

I would check if the user is logged in the Login View using `viewDidLoad()`. If yes, it will open User Profile View.

---

However, if a user is logged in, this method would open Login View for about 1s before going to User Profile View.

Is there a better method to check if user logged in, before deciding which screen to open?

---

### Storyboard

[image]

---

### Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
    if (isLoggedIn == 1) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_userprofile", sender: self)
    }
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Is the login or profile view the first thing shows when user opens app?

Comment: @RyanTobin Login is first shown

Comment: But if the user is logged in, then profile is shown?

Comment: @RyanTobin Yes, however, since I'm checking it using `viewDidLoad()` it will show Login View briefly before opening User Profile View. How can I get rid of Login View briefing showing?

Comment: So you need to do the check in func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as opposed to viewDidLoad(). You then need to set a storyboard ID in IB and you can change your view controller that way. This will prevent the login screen from flashing. I have code written to do this, but it is in objective-c. I can post it if you would like so you can get an idea

Comment: @RyanTobin Thanks, would it be possible to post your Objective-C code?

Comment: Yes let me create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as opposed to viewDidLoad() to prevent the flashing of the login screen.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    NSString *board = @"your storyboard file name"
    NSString *identifier;
    NSString *user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"your key"];

    if(user != nil){
        identifier = @"profile";
        //User is logged in. Go to profile page
    }
    else
        identifier = @"login";
        //User is not logged in. Go to login page

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:board bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=10;
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

After implementing this code in your AppDelegate file, you need to open your storyboard file in interface builder.

[image]

You need to locate this above in the identity inspector. On your login view controller set the Storyboard ID to login. Set the profile View Controller Storyboard ID to profile. Once again, sorry this is in Objective-C, but I hope this helps!

Comment: I've managed to convert the code to Swift, however, my Profile View now doesn't show Navigation Bar, is there a fix to that?

Comment: It's likely caused by `goto_userprofile` segue not running

Comment: I would assume so. Was the navigation bar supposed to go anywhere or just display?

Comment: It should display as there are buttons for Logout (leads back to Login View) and Settings

Comment: You can try adding a navigation controller that is linked to the profile. Set the Storyboard ID of the navigation controller to profile as opposed to the profile page. It should then go directly to the profile through the navigation and display bar. @luweiqi

Comment: If that does not work, the only other thing I can think of would be to take the code you previously had in the viewDidLoad() and place it in viewWillAppear(). viewWillAppear is supposed to render before the view actually appears. @luweiqi

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'm trying it out, will update if it worked :)

Comment: I've managed to make it by moving the splash screen to Main.storyboard and check it in the splash screen instead. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Okay awesome. No problem and I am glad that you figured it out @luweiqi